# Seaborn bivariate KDE speed-up

Tags: python, seaborn

I am estimating a Gaussian bivariate KDE of positions data (x and y coordinates), and I use `sns.kdeplot` for this. While it works correctly (i.e. I get the plot I get), it is pretty slow for the amount of data I have (can by up to 0.5 million (x,y) pairs).

1. What is complexity of `kdeplot` as implemented in `seaborn`? I cannot seem to find this information. Is it "classic" $O(nm)$ KDE complexity?
2. Are there freely available implementations of KDE plots that are faster than in `seaborn`?
3. Are there some preprocessing methods for locations data that can speed-up the calculations? I have read answers to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105623/how-to-speed-up-kernel-density-estimation, but I am have not fully understood it, and I am also not sure if it is directly applicable to my type of data. Of the answers to that questions, what would be the preferred method for the locations data? Are k-D trees a good approach to it? Is it already implemented like this in `seaborn` (or in some other library), or I should write my own implementation?

Comment: Also see: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/219833/density-estimation-for-large-dataset/219913#219913